# ACM template: Where should I put \acmprice{} to avoid "undefined control sequence"?

Tags: acm

The editor told me to put \acmPrice{} right after \isbn{}, but I got an "undefined control sequence" error and a "missing \begin{document}" error.

Comment: Could you at least provide the community with some form of working code so we can be on the same page? Please provide code in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` so we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `acmart` class defines `\acmPrice` and uses it to initialise things as

```
\acmPrice{15}
```

Note you have `\acmprice` with a small `p` in the question.

`acmconf` class does not define this command.

Comment: Thank you. Actually the template provided for _siggraph_ paper does not contain an `\acmprice` tag, neither `\acmPrice` with capital P. The editor just let me not to add this tag.